# Ansible conditional lists

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'd like to deploy to different directories depending on a flag.

I saw there was `--extra-vars` which allows passing in a variable,

so let's say, `--extra-vars "flag=test"` or `--extra-vars "flag=prod"`

Now I'd like to either use the test_* or prod_* variables, depending on this flag.

```
  vars:
    test_dirs: ["/dataVolumes/dev/deployments/", "/dataVolumes/qa/deployments/"]

    prod_dirs: ["/dataVolumes/preprod/deployments/", "/dataVolumes/prod/deployments/"]
```

Let's say there's two steps, delete old files, and copy new files.

Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
-
  name: delete old files
  file: 
   state:absent 
   path:"{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{ test_dirs if flag == 'test' else prod_dirs }}"

-
  name: copy new files
  copy:
   src: /opt/ansible/
   dest:"{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{ test_dirs if flag == 'test' else prod_dirs }}"
```

Like, a conditional operator, to choose between two lists to work with?

Comment: are you running the play on the same hosts? why aren't you using `group_vars` ?

Comment: yeah, dev/qa/prod are all on the same host, so though it's useful to know about `group_vars`, after reading the docs on that page, I'm still unsure how to specify which group to use, based on a condition.  I suppose I could define the same hosts in different groups though.  Hmm.  That might be it.  Will check

Comment: Yes. You can add the same host to multiple host groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by adding a [include_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html) task at the beginning of your play. As variables set by `include_vars` have a high [precedence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) they should rule out the variables set elsewhere.

So all you need to do is add something like this at the beginning of your play:

```
- name: Include test vars.
  include_vars:
     file: test.yml
  when: test == True
```

the value of the variable test would then need to be a boolean.

However as already pointed out using `group_vars` would likely be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks I agree, after looking at the two options, `group_vars` seems cleaner.  I got it working in the end, thanks.  with_items worked for processing the list, in all of my tasks

Comment: @djb It would make this question more useful for the long term if you wrote an answer including brief sample code for the two different ways to solve this problem using `include_vars` and `group_vars`.  The answers and comments assume knowledge not held.  Or maybe Henrik's answer could be modified to show how it would work using `group_vars`.

Comment: Well here's a link to the docs: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#group-variables